# Invalid type and ID field error

Tags: unit-test, class, lookup-field

Good day,
I"m trying to write this class. But I'm getting an:

> "Invalid type:Occurence__c"

error. Also it's showing `invalid ID field: myOcc`.
Can't figure out what I'm missing, please assist.

Here is the code:

```
public class OccurenceCalculatorTEMPORARY {

        public static void calculateOcc(List<Occurrence__c> myOcc)
        {
            List<Claim__c> AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence  = new List<Claim__c>();
            AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence = [Select Name, Initial_estimate__c from Claim__c where Occurrence__c = 'myOcc'];

            //set Claim Value to 0
            Decimal TotalClaimValue=0;

            For(Claim__c Item: AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence)
            {
                TotalClaimValue = TotalClaimValue + Item.Initial_estimate__c;
            }
            system.debug(TotalClaimValue);

                For(Claim__c Item: AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence)
                {
                    Item.Excess__c = (Item.Initial_estimate__c/TotalClaimValue) * Item.Policy_Excess__c;
                    Item.Captive_Stop_Loss_Estimate_Override__c = (Item.Initial_estimate__c/TotalClaimValue) * Item.Stop_Loss_Limit__c;

                }

            update AllClaimsLinkedToOccurrence;            
        }
}
```

Comment: There error is because there is no custom object named `Invalid type:Occurence__c` also it doesn't exist in your provided code, In your code only reference is of `Occurrence__c`. This could be a small typo?

Comment: @Raul thanks for the heads up. You're right, it was a typo. The object name is RK_Occurrence__c.

Comment: `Occurrence__c = 'myOcc'`, also here if you the field type is lookup, it would need a valid Id

Comment: @Raul how would I go about assigning a valid Id?

Answer (score -1):

It is clear the custom field Occurrence__c is missing in your query

```
[Select Name, Initial_estimate__c from Claim__c where Occurrence__c = 'myOcc'];
```

Please include the custom field in this Query hopefully it will resolve your issue.

```
[Select Name, Initial_estimate__c,Occurrence__c from Claim__c where Occurrence__c = 'myOcc'];
```

Comment: Let me try this and I will revert back. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to include a field in the `SELECT` clause to be able to use it as a filter in the `WHERE` clause.